# How do I write a Delphi Galileo IDE Expert?

Tags: delphi, ide, galileo, ota

HI,

I want to write a small Delphi IDE Expert for D2007-D2009 (aka. Galileo IDE) in order to show a window with a TMemo instance on it, with all the component names and classes from the form designer in the above memo. The selected component will be marked with a '*'. The expert should appear on a menu/toolbar and have a shortcut assigned.

*How do I do?*

Ps: Actually the real code is more complicated than that, but I want to have a general framework to get started.

TIA

Comment: It should work the same as it did for earlier versions. Which part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did my first OTA with help of these links:

[Erik's Open Tools API FAQ and Resources](http://www.gexperts.org/opentools/) (The author of GExpert)

[Delphi Open Tools API](http://www.mustangpeak.net/opentoolsape.htm) from Jim Kueneman - Mustangpeak

[Delphi Open Tools API](http://www.tempest-sw.com/opentools/) from RayRay Lischner

They are not updated to the latest versions, but they will you good start point and most of the code will work with the last version, I tried them with D2007.

Comment: You should also check out the source code to gExperts and cnPack, and the JCL wizards (comes in the JEDI Class Library sources)

Answer (score 3):

There are links to articles describing how to write an OTA plug-in here:
http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/wizardsexperts.htm