# Delphi Open tools Api creating a project wizard

Tags: delphi, toolsapi

I am trying to create a project wizard and am totaly new to the open tools api.

I got the following questions.
Is it possible to save the project to a specific loaction and if so how can I do that. My wizard asks for the location.

I create a new form but it has the name Form1. I like to give it a specific name. How can I do that?

I like to copy a datamodule to my project. How can I tell the wizard to copy the file and save it in the project directory with a different name?

Answer (score 1):

As a start look at this question [Create a Simple Delphi IDE Expert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488873/create-a-simple-delphi-ide-expert)

look also here
http://www.mustangpeak.net/ (view the wizard section) and here:
http://www.tempest-sw.com/opentools/

best regards,
Radu