# Custom component on delphi loading screen

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

How can I make my custom visual control to appear on delphi splash screen?

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here you go
http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_3870.asp?SK=

I don't have now the time to create a fully functional example, but I believe this link will help you a lot.

LE: I've found some examples here:
http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_4620.asp?SK=

and here
http://www.mail-archive.com/delphi-talk@elists.org/msg00870.html

Comment: This seems to be for Delphi .NET which is obsolete.

Comment: yes Ulrich, it is a combined example. but as you mentioned in your answer JustMe must start from IOTASplashScreenServices.If JustMe did not worked with OTA until now, there he has some articles from where to start.

Comment: @Radu Thanks, those link were very helpful. Is there any OTA documentation from embarcadero or you just need to read the ToolsApi source code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488873/create-a-simple-delphi-ide-expert and also very useful www.mustangpeak.net/opentoolsape.htm

Comment: Thanks. All of this is sooo old, Embarcadero don't care about it or what?

Comment: Embarcadero just published a NEW white paper on OTAPI, and there is a webinar coming up with Bruno Fierens of TMS.  Check it out on the  www.embarcadero.com site.  http://www.embarcadero.com/rad-in-action/otapi

Answer (score 2):

Searching the ToolsAPI folder in my Delphi installation for "Splash" yields `SplashScreenServices: IOTASplashScreenServices;` whose comments read promising.