# how to install Source Wizard for Delphi 7 in Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I have Source Wizard for Delphi 7 (a code formatter).
I'm switching to Delphi 2009. I tried loading *.pas (created with D2009) in Source Wizard in Delphi 7 and there were no problems processing them.
How can I make it to show like a menu item in D2009's menu..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have an item in the tools menu, you can simply click on Tools->Configure Tools (or similar, I have a German Delphi version here).

If you are trying to port a Delphi 7 OTA (Open Tools API) wizard, you have to change the code to the new API, because it changed in the transition from the Aurora IDE (D1 - D7) to the Galileo IDE (D8+).

[How do I write a Delphi Galileo IDE Expert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102668/how-do-i-write-a-delphi-galileo-ide-expert)

Or are you asking for a specific tool that is called "Source Wizard"?

PS: It would not hurt to clarify your question a bit. A more specific question gets you better answers.

**Edit:** You may look at GExperts for the integrated source formatter that is based on DelForExp like the "Delphi Source Wizard" seems to be:

http://www.dummzeuch.de/delphi/gexperts/english.html

Comment: It is a specific tool. You can find informations at: http://www.brothersoft.com/delphi-source-formatting-wizard-789.html

Comment: Ok, so you are trying to get an old code formatter integrated into the 2009 IDE? You might have a look at alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402737/delphi-code-formatter

Comment: It seems that "Source Wizard" is based on DelForExp: http://www.aew.wur.nl/UK/Delforexp/